# Displaying in a meter chart column values

Tags: charts, birt

Before beginning I'd want to specifiy that I'm working with BIRT 4.8, and that I'm a complete beginner when it comes to BIRT.

**My main question is:** Is there a way to display the maximum value of columns in a meter chart?

I want to put the following values into a meter chart :

[Image showing the data I intend to put into a meter chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yiDcb.png)

To do so I used for example this line of code to make a computed column:

[Image showing the variable coding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5xpv.png)

In this case, everytime there is an open case, an external variable (open_inter) is incremented by +1.

What I wih to obtain is the following:

[Image showing what I wish to have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwOcZ.png)

I used an aggregation to ask for the maximum value of each column, in this case 14 and 13 were the maximum. I did this since putting multiple values into a single meter chart seems illogical.

But I didn't receive the expected result, instead in the preview of the data in my chart I got this:

[Image showing false values from the data sets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NC7pL.png)

Later I created report parameters to put the maximum value of each variable in. Those worked fine without the meter chart, but once again it did not display correctly once implemented.

While I hope that I explained myself clearly, I thank you in advance, and I wish you all a wonderful day.